# Limit Question: lim theta---> 0 sin theta / 3 theta + tan theta: When you multiply 1/ cos theta by 1/ theta why doesn't your value change?

Tags: calculus

I am having a hard time understanding why the 1/cosine term does not change to lets say cosine theta squared? Can someone explain why? [image]

Comment: do you mean why not to put the theta inside the cosine function?

Comment: Why is cosine not changed when it is multiplied by 1/theta?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question? Please read the question before flagging.

Comment: why should it? what rule would you be using? or what rule do you think was not done correctly in the example above? remember that theta is just a factor and you can chose where to "move" it, but you cannot put it inside the cosine function

Comment: @user137452 Question don't need to be the same to be closed as duplicates. If they are similar enough, it's perfectly reasonable to close as a duplicate. In my opinion, these are similar enough.

Comment: What do you mean that theta is just a factor? Aren't factors real numbers? Isn't theta a variable for degrees / rads?

Answer (score 0):

Easier: rewrite it as $\frac{\sin x }{4x(1+\frac{\sin x}{4 x \cos x})} = \frac{\sin x }{x} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{\sin x}{4x \cos x}}$ and use the properties you have mentioned in the post. Since $\cos x$ tends to 1 it doens't change the result, and the rest follows by continuity.

Comment: I rather have the question that I asked answered since I have been solving this type of problem using that format. Why is it that when one multiplies 1/cos theta by 1 / theta it does not change cosine but does change all the other terms?

Comment: What you probably mean is why you can rewrite $\lim_x \frac{\sin x}{x \cos x} = \lim_x \frac{\sin x}{x} \lim_x \frac{1}{\cos x}$. This is because both limits exist and are finite.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin \theta}{4\theta+\tan\theta} = \frac{\sin \theta}{4\theta+\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos\theta}}$$

Now dividing numerator and denominator by $\theta$ (or multiplying by 1 over theta), we have

$$\frac{\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}}{\frac{4\theta}{\theta} +\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta\cos\theta}} = \frac{\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}}{4 +\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta\cos\theta}}$$

So, since $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = 1$

we have $$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}}{4 +\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}\cdot \frac 1{\cos\theta}} = \frac{1}{4 +1\cdot \frac 1{1}} = \frac 15$$